# Arreglos (Requiero una mano en el resto de los puntos)

Tags: java, array

Quería ver si podían ayudarme en el resto, solo tengo hasta el momento el punto 1 (Inserto código mas abajo)

Se requiere leer y guardar las edades de 15 personas y almacenarlas en un vector. Posteriormente:

1. Obtener y mostrar cuál es la mayor y la menor edad almacenada.
2. Obtener e imprimir las edades de las personas mayores de edad y cuántas hay.
3. Leer una edad cualquiera, calcular y mostrar el número de personas que tienen esa edad.
4. Calcular y mostrar el promedio de edades que se guardaron, obtener y mostrar las edades que son superiores a ese promedio.

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Ejercicio { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
     Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
     int mayor = 0; int menor = 0;
     int[] edades = new int[15]; 

     for (int i = 0+1; i < 15; i++) {
       System.out.print("Ingrese el número " + (i) + " a evaluar :"); 
       edades[i] = dato.nextInt(); 
     } 
     for (int i = 1; i < edades.length; i++) {
       if (mayor < edades[i]) { 
         mayor = edades[i];
       } 
     } 
     menor = mayor; 

     for (int i = 1; i < edades.length; i++) {
       if (menor > edades[i]) {
         menor = edades[i]; 
       } 
     }
     System.out.println(" el numero mayor es " + mayor + " el numero menor es :" + menor); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Por favor mejora el título de tu pregunta, sin contar con el hecho de que el código va como texto por favor, si tienes dudas checa [ask]

Comment: Ya hice la corrección, puse el código en texto

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y mejora el título de tu pregunta: _requiero una mano con_... no nos dice nada, y tampoco será de ayuda para otros usuarios más adelante.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías plantear mejor tu consulta, me parece que el título no es el más adecuado pero te entiendo porque eres nuevo en la comunidad y seguramente en tus próximas preguntas lo harás mejor.
Te comparto una de las múltiples soluciones que puede tener tus consultas. Me confirmas si es lo que buscas.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Ejercicio { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner dato = new Scanner(System.in);
        int mayoresEdad=0,mayorLeerEdad=0,sumaEdades=0,mayoresQuePromedio=0;
        double promedio;
        int leerEdad;
        
        //Se requiere leer y guardar las edades de 15 personas y almacenarlas en un vector
        ArrayList<Integer> edades = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i <15; i++) { 
            System.out.print("Ingrese la edad " + (i+1)+" :" );
            edades.add(dato.nextInt());             
        }
        Collections.sort(edades);//Ordenamos las edades 
        
        //1. Obtener y mostrar cuál es la mayor y la menor edad almacenada.        
        System.out.println("\nMenor edad del arreglo: "+edades.get(0));
        System.out.println("Mayor edad del arreglo: "+edades.get(14));
        System.out.println("");
        
        //2. Obtener e imprimir las edades de las personas mayores de edad y cuántas hay.
        ArrayList<Integer> edades2 = new ArrayList();
        for(Integer i:edades){
            if(i>=18){
                mayoresEdad++;
                edades2.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Edades mayores de 18");
        for(Integer i:edades2){            
            System.out.print(i+",");
        }
        System.out.println("Cantidad de personas mayores de edad: "+mayoresEdad);
        System.out.println("");
        
        //3. Leer una edad cualquiera, calcular y mostrar el número de personas que tienen esa edad.
        System.out.println("Ingrese una edad para comparar: ");
        leerEdad=dato.nextInt();
        for(Integer i:edades){
            if(i==leerEdad) mayorLeerEdad++;
        }
        System.out.println("Cantidad de personas iguales que la edad ingresada: "+mayorLeerEdad);
        System.out.println("");
        
        //4. Calcular y mostrar el promedio de edades que se guardaron, obtener y mostrar las edades que son superiores a ese promedio.   
        ArrayList<Integer> edades3 = new ArrayList();
        for(Integer i:edades){            
           sumaEdades=sumaEdades+i; 
        } 
        promedio=sumaEdades/15;
        for(Integer i:edades){
            if(i>promedio){
                mayoresQuePromedio++;                
            }
        }        
        System.out.println("Promedio de Edades: "+promedio);
        for(Integer i:edades){
            if(i>promedio){
                mayoresEdad++;
                edades3.add(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Edades mayores que el promedio de edades");
        for(Integer i:edades3){            
            System.out.print(i+",");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Aunque tu intención es buena, _procura no responder a preguntas de baja calidad_. Lee [answer]. Ten en cuenta que este no es un servicio para hacer la tarea de los demás, sino un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: Como lo habían editado su pregunta, me animé a responder; para la próxima tendré en cuenta tus recomendaciones